# Is Doofenshmirtz Evil Incorporated an actual company (in-universe)?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

Is Doofenshmirtz Evil Incorporated, the company of Dr. Doofenshmirtz, an actual legitimate company? Does it actually produce or sell anything?

It has a blimp, [which a sports announcer recognizes as belonging to Doofenshmirtz Evil Incorporated](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fast_and_the_Phineas) and [it owns several buildings around town](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Doofenshmirtz_Evil_Incorporated), but Doofenshmirtz never seems to do any real business things.

So is it an actual company, or just a front/vanity project?

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, Doofenshmirtz's inventions, Perry's spyware and the boys' creations are all science fiction, so *Phineas and Ferb* should be on-topic.

Comment: A blue platypus who acts like a human sounds plenty sci-fi-ish to me, as well.

Comment: They have a large downtown building with the company's name on it; http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/phineasandferb/images/8/88/Doofenshmirtz_Evil_Inc._2.png/revision/latest?cb=20090917230920

Comment: http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Doofenshmirtz_Evil_Incorporated

Comment: Isn't it just a fake company, and all of the schemes, buildings, assets all funded purely by money Doof gets from his ex-wife?

Comment: It could be a real company, but just one that doesn't produce anything. What do we mean by "real" anyway? Maybe he's just managing real estate, or perhaps he's a really terrible (thus perpetually clientless) consultant?

Comment: @pleurocoelus: It doesn't work that way. We have a precedent that a blue octopus who pretends to be a human doesn't make something science fiction, even if he makes an uglifying ray with mad science.

Comment: @b_jonas Learn something new every day... I was going for humor, but I guess I should have indicated such in a better way.

Comment: I feel like he mentioned having to do taxes for his company at one point but I'm not sure lol

Comment: In the monster truck episode, Doof does try to attract investors to purchase his latest Inator.  And in another episode his is upset because on of his Inators is being used to help people, even though he is making a ton of money off of it.  Too busy to look up citations now.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the Phineas and Ferb wiki link that Richard posted the page says:

> Doofenshmirtz Evil Incorporated, also known as Doofenshmirtz Evil Inc. or Doofenshmirtz Corporation, is a company owned by the evil scientist Dr. Heinz Doofenshmirtz. Most of the daily operations of the company are run by Doofenshmirtz himself. The main purpose of the company is to assist Dr. Doofenshmirtz is his schemes to conquer the Tri-State Area.

So presumably the company is a front for his evil doings and other various ventures.

Comment: That page doesn't have any citations or sources. I would need some direct quotes before I accepted this.

Comment: I think that's as direct as you'll find man. They never address it.